# Unity - job system compatibility for end user?

Tags: unity, .net

I'm thinking about using [Job system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html). But it requires .Net 4.x (also look like [.Net 4.x will be default for Unity in 2019](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/07/11/scripting-runtime-improvements-in-unity-2018-2/)). It is a little hassle for me cause I'm using Visual Studio 2015, I have to download & install [.Net target pack 4.7](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks)

My question is: If my game is developed with .Net 4.7.2 (so that I can use Job system), does it require the end user installing .Net 4.7.2 to play the game?

My target user is low-end PC (they may using windows 7, [I see that .NET Framework 3.5.1 is included in Windows 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/))

Answer (score 1):

.NET is not installed onto the computer in the same way something like Java is. .NET is handled through the OS and Unity's additional functionality is given in the build.

According to your link, if Windows 7 is a key part of your demographic, you will lose some functionality that is in .NET 4.x that isn't in .NET Standard 2.0. While the job system will require 4.x, Unity's policy is to try and build as much of their game on .NET Standard as possible, to avoid situations like this. There will likely be sections of the job system you can use and others you can't on Windows 7. If you want to use the job system, you will need to research which parts of the game are built on 4.x and use SystemInfo.operatingSystem or similar to create special code for the OS not built on .NET 4.x

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html

Comment: So if my user have a .NET 3.5, then the game crash when they open it, or it can be played but slow?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it will likely play at normal speed, with functions missing code breaking.

Comment: "with functions missing code breaking" - You mean the game will crash?

Comment: could crash, or more likely the function will stop at the bad code

Comment: @123iamkingen Your users won't "only have .NET 3.5" in the same sense that they'll "only have Internet Explorer." When they get your game, it'll *come packaged with a .NET 4.x runtime.* Ever installed a game to have it install other things, like ".net runtime" or "dx 11"? That's what is doing: installing the exact version of .net it needs to run.